# Why do I get an unnecessary blank page between abstract and acknowledgement?

Tags: memoir, abstract, blank-page

There is an unnecessary blank page between abstract and acknowledgement.

The content of `abstract.tex` is between `\begin{abstract}` and `\end{abstract}`. The content of `ack.tex` starts with `\chapter*{Acknowledgement}`.

Can you tell me how I can remove this blank page? More importantly why am I getting this blank page? Acknowledgement is starting at 8th page in the generated pdf while abstract finishes at 6th page.

The same problem (blank page) occurs between the last chapter and author's publications. The content of `pub.tex` starts with `\chapter*{Author's Publications}`.

Another problem is that despite doing an `openright` except the first chapter all my chapters are beginning on an even numbered page. I thought these two might be related.

UPDATE: A compilable file

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, openright]{memoir}

% \includeonly{./chapters/conclusion/conclusion}

\usepackage{graphicx} % For inserting graphics in the page
\usepackage{epstopdf} % For automatically converting eps images to pdf while using pdflatex
\usepackage{dblfloatfix} % For using a "b" as placement specifier for a page wide image
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % For ensuring correct image numbering when we use \figure*
\usepackage{mathtools} % For using mathematics environments
\usepackage{amsfonts} % For using text formatting in equations eg \mathbf
\usepackage{algorithm} % For wrapping algorithmic environment to produce a floating environment.
\usepackage{algorithmic} % For using algorithmic environment
\usepackage{threeparttable} % For adding footnotes to the table
\usepackage{subcaption} % For putting multiple figures within a single figure environment
\usepackage{tikz} % For drawing

\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}

\begin{document}
\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage

% title page
\begin{titlingpage}
    ASD
\end{titlingpage}

% page numbering with roman
\pagenumbering{roman}
% Increase line spacing
\DoubleSpacing

% abstract
\begin{abstract}
    Asd
\end{abstract}

% Acknowledgement
\chapter*{Acknowledgement}
    Asd

% Table of contents
\newpage
\tableofcontents

% List of figures
\newpage
\listoffigures

% List of tables
\newpage
\listoftables

\mainmatter

% Reset page numbering with arabic
\pagenumbering {arabic}

\chapter{Intro}
    Asd
\chapter{Literature}
    Asd
\chapter{GSNN}
    Asd
\chapter{SASNN}
    Asd
\chapter{Conclusions}
    Asd

\backmatter
\chapter*{Author's Publications}
    Asd

\end{document}
```

UPDATE: The blank page between abstract is coming because going by the numbering in the document abstract ends at iii and since I use `\chapter*` achnowledgement begins on page iv. I tried cutting down the abstract to finish it on page ii then there is no blank page. Can someone tell me how I can suppress this blank page or is there a better alternative?

UPDATE: The even numbered pages was because I was using `\include` which uses `\clearpage`. After I use `\input` all chapters are now beginning on odd numbered pages.

Comment: Each `\chapter` always start on a right hand side no matter if you use `\chapter*` or `\chapter`. An next time, please provide something that is compilable.

Comment: Thanks for replying.....I understand that all chapters start on the right hand side whether you use \chapter or \chapter*. This means that all chapter begin on odd numbered pages which is not the case in the original code (uncompilable) I submitted but is the case in new code (compilable). And I have no clue why. This is another problem I pointed in the question. Although in the compilable file also there is a blank page between abstract and acknowledgement

Comment: Have you tried changing the document option `openright` to `openany`?

Comment: Please delete the first example (we can't run it so it doesn't help) and edit the second example so that it shows the problem (perhaps if I understand your comment correctly it needs a 2-page abstract?) delete `\bibliography{../../../Bibliography/Bibtex/SNN}` as that would cause a difference for you locally if you have the file.

Comment: My problem is that I need a way to suppress the addition of a page between abstract and acknowledgement. A page is added to allow each chapter to begin at the right hand side.

Answer (score 2):

The blank page between the abstract and the acknowledgements appears because you are using `\chapter*` for the latter. This executes the `\cleartorecto` macro, which inserts the blank page, so that the acknowledgements start on a recto page. The simplest thing to do is temporarily change the meaning of `\cleartorecto` so that it just starts a new page.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, openright]{memoir}
\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}
\begin{document}
\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage

\begin{titlingpage}
    ASD
\end{titlingpage}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\DoubleSpacing

\begin{abstract}
    Asd
\end{abstract}

\let\oldcleartorecto\cleartorecto % <--- new
\let\cleartorecto\newpage         % <--- new
\chapter*{Acknowledgement}
\let\cleartorecto\oldcleartorecto % <--- new; restores original macro

    Asd

\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables

\mainmatter

\pagenumbering {arabic}

\chapter{Intro}
    Asd
\chapter{Literature}
    Asd
\chapter{GSNN}
    Asd
\chapter{SASNN}
    Asd
\chapter{Conclusions}
    Asd

\backmatter
\chapter*{Author's Publications}
    Asd
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This blank page is for printing. Ff you print the document(and selected the memoir template) you usually want the written pages to be on the "right" side. The empty page is more or less a cover for the "left" side.