# In memoir class how do I force the abstract on the title page and be of type chapter?

Tags: memoir, titles

For my thesis proposal I'd like to use memoir document class. I'd like to have the abstract on the title page *and* set to:

```
\abstractnum   % Format heading as chapter
\abstractintoc % Include "Abstract" in ToC
```

And have the sections numbered with arabic numbers rather than roman?

Here is what I have:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 11pt, twoside, openright, english]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% Abstract: Remove indents around abstract text
\setlength{\absleftindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\absrightindent}{0pt}
% Change font size to conform with the rest of the document text
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalsize}

\abstractnum   % Format heading as chapter
\abstractintoc % Include "Abstract" in ToC

\title{ my title}
\author{Sal MaName}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
% \pagestyle{empty}
% \aliaspagestyle{chapter}{empty}

\maketitle
% \mainmatter

\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum[1]
  \lipsum[2]
  \lipsum[3]
\end{abstract}

\pagebreak

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\section{Overview\label{sec:Overview}}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a first attempt. Not sure if I missed something, though.

For the first question, the easiest way is to suppress the page breaks between the title and the abstract.

For the second question, I think that's fixed with the `\mainmatter` command, which starts numbering chapters, changes page numbering to Arabic, etc.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 11pt, twoside, openright, english]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% Abstract: Remove indents around abstract text
\setlength{\absleftindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\absrightindent}{0pt}
% Change font size to conform with the rest of the document text
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalsize}

\abstractnum   % Format heading as chapter
\abstractintoc % Include "Abstract" in ToC

\title{My Title}
\author{Sal MaName}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

% Adapted from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187904/3345
\let\oldcleartorecto\cleartorecto
\let\cleartorecto\relax
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\let\cleartorecto\oldcleartorecto

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{One}
\section{Overview\label{sec:Overview}}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent! Yes, this is good place to start!